# Outputing text to a file?

Tags: java, text

After running my program I get this beautifully formatted text:[image]

What do I need add to my code in order to get this text outputted to a .txt file exactly as is?

Comment: :Is your program written by other?

Comment: I wrote the program myself in BlueJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're currently writing your output to the screen using something like `System.out.Println(...)`, a comparable way to write text to a file is to use a PrintStream.

You should be able to find many examples of how to do that if you search; [here's one](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/printstream.shtml).

```
import java.io.*;

class PrintStreamDemo {  
  public static void main(String args[]){ 
   FileOutputStream out; 
  PrintStream ps; // declare a print stream object
  try {
 // Create a new file output stream
  out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

  // Connect print stream to the output stream
  ps = new PrintStream(out);

  ps.println ("This data is written to a file:");
  System.err.println ("Write successfully");
  ps.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println ("Error in writing to file");
  }
  }
}
```

ps. one caution: the "beautifully formatted" part of your text probably relies on the output being displayed in a monospaced font (all characters the same width); if viewed in a non-monospaced font, the columns won't line up. If you're saving it as a plain .txt file, you don't have control over what font someone else will use to display that file when they open it.

---

Update:

There are a couple of approaches you could take, if you find you've got a program full of `System.out.println` calls and you want to direct the output to a file instead.

1) The quick & dirty way would be to open a PrintStream to your desired output file, then call `System.setOut()` to redirect `System.out` to the specified PrintStream.

2) A perhaps cleaner way would be to rewrite all the calls of `System.out.println` to use your own output method. That way when you want to change how you're handling output (for example, send it to multiple files, to both the screen and a file, or whatever), you have just one place to change. More work up front, but gives you more flexibility in the end.

Comment: My program is many lines and consists of many methods. I can't stick a "out.print..." in front of every line.

Comment: Well I could but it would be a huge pain and take a lot of time. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how you're generating the output now? What method(s) are you calling to write it to the screen?

Comment: A bunch of System.outprintln and a bunch of loops

Comment: That is not important, tho. Do you know a way to save text that does not use the printWriter?

Comment: I'll cehck out the System.ssetOut thanks David i'll register and rate you.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt clarify where data come from, but anyway input or db, I would place on a multidimensional array. Then print will be easy.

P.S. Also to keep format I would use tab separated values "/t"

public class Parser {

```
private void parseData{

    int[][] array = new int[3][12];
     // print array in rectangular form
     for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++) {

         for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++) {

             System.out.print(array[r][c] + "\t");
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }

}
```

}